# How can i get the activated services for a user in the SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Database and insert the last status of each service activation for users.

```
logid  |  userid     |  serviceid  |  status
-------+-------------+-------------+--------
1      |  123456789  |      a      |      0
2      |  123456789  |      b      |      1
3      |  123456789  |      b      |      0
4      |  123456789  |      a      |      1
5      |  123456789  |      c      |      1
6      |  123456789  |      a      |      0
7      |  123456789  |      d      |      1
```

1)How can i have a select query that returns active services for a user? 
for example: in above table, i need to get c,d where userid = 123456789

2)Is it OK to add another field on table to store current status and write a trigger to update current status for all records on row insert? (it works but takes long time on millions records)

3)Is there a query to read all records one by one and update current status to last status that i run it after all records inserted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

answer for your first question:

```
select t.serviceid
from Log t
where t.status=1 and userid=123456789
group by t.logid,t.serviceid
having t.logid=(select max(tt.logid) from Log tt where tt.serviceid=t.serviceid)
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ff99/5

Comment: Hi my friend. thank you. your query works perfect in sqlfiddle.com but it doesn't return any record in my local system!!! I use SQL Server 2012 too.

Comment: very strange, I try it on my local system and it works!

Answer (score 0):

1: using SQL. The simple sql you learn in the first 20 pages of a book about SQL - which I would say you should.

select userid, serviceid from whateveryoourtablename where status = 1

I get the idea that this likely is not what you asked for, but hey - you enver explain the business rules clear enough.

2: Yes and no. Why would a user logging in update millions of rows? THAT would be a problem. A user / service table containing active services that is maintained by a trigger is doable and a user login will NOT update millions of rows.

3: Not clear what you are asking. But yes, such a query exists. It is trivial to make the update if you get hte last status and that is trivial too.

Answer (score 0):

For what it worth, I would have a separate table with service status

```
statusid  |  userid     |  serviceid  |  status
----------+-------------+-------------+--------
1         |  123456789  |      a      |      0
2         |  123456789  |      b      |      0
3         |  123456789  |      c      |      1
4         |  123456789  |      d      |      1
```

I would have a unique constraint on userid, serviceid, or alternatively make these two columns the primary key instead of the id column, if appropriate, the id column can be removed in this case. I would also put a trigger on the log table and update the status in this new status table. Note that this would only update a single record.